# Allegro ACS37002 - Noise Issue

Tags: current-measurement

I have a noise issue with the Allegro ACS37002LLAATR-015B3 (+-10A), where I see HF noise in the VIOUT signal of about +-50mV at no load attached to the sensor, which would be equivalent of around +-400mA at a measurement range of only +-10A:

[image]

Since this is only a own designed eval board and there are no noise sources I could find, I don't see why the output signal of the CSA (Current Sense Amplifier) looks like this other than the sensor is that noisy.

Schematic (C17 and C18 were initially not placed and also placing 1nF on it did not resolve it):

[image]

The layout should be more than good enough (two tightly connected internal ground planes, top signal/GND and bot signal/3V3), especially since there is only a 3.3V LDO on it next to the CSA and everything is supplied by a low noise linear PSU. Also I do not see any noise on the VREF pin and also the 3.3V supply is extremly low noise.

Since I measure directly with a spring clamp and VREF aswell VIOUT also with a SMA connector, it is definitely not a measurement issue. I also removed the TLV9004 differential amplifier and measured only VIOUT, which leaded to exactly the same behaviour.

Any ideas if I did something wrong with this IC or if the IC is really that noisy?

3D:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

C17 and C18 should go between R1/R2 to ground and R4/R5 to ground, respectively. The way it is drawn, the current-sense op-amp doesn't have proper filtering.

Comment: The thing is, the sensor should be low noise enough without any filtering to keep high enough bandwidth when they state high accuracy, low noise.

Comment: @HansPeterLoft Maybe the noise isn't real. What is the noise floor of the oscilloscope?

Comment: It definitely is, the noise floor is 5mVrms and I can measure the Vref signal with nearly now noise, on all 3 boards.

Comment: Those parts are based on the hall-effect, which means they are subject to external magnetic fields that my be interfering. Also, could you run the circuit off a battery? Maybe you have a ground loop between circuit ground and oscilloscope ground and you are measuring CM noise.

Comment: I dont have a ground loop, directly measured with the SMA connector (on the test pcb) and also a spring probe. Especially since I can measure the Vref and supply voltage without any significant noise (around the noise floor) the measurement is not the issue, the sensor really produces this ouput. Further, it is stated, that the sensor has suppression of strong external magnetic field and there arent any strong ones anyway at thr moment around. A battery I already tried without improvement.

Comment: What I see in thr datasheet is something like a noise stated as mVrms of 160mVs, but I dont see what kind of noise this is and if maybe this sensor is really high in accuracy and really low in precision

Comment: Well based on that 160mVRMS spec. you're performing better than the datasheet!

Comment: The thing is, i dont know what kind of noise „low noise LA package“ is? It is not stated as output noise, so I really dont see the expected noise from the datasheet of the sensor

Comment: The chip really is that noisy - noise figures are given on page 9. This can easily be filtered at the expense of bandwidth. "low-noise" may be relative to hall-effect technology which is inherently noisy compared to traditional current-sense techniques.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151166/discussion-between-hanspeterloft-and-mosfet).